# VPS memory full, no process using it, no ballooning, no tmpfs

Tags: vps, memory-usage

I'm using a 512MB VPS which is just running Apache (no traffic) and a crontab backup to Onedrive using Restic every couple couple of hours.
I'm experiencing high memory and moderate swap consumption, apparently with no responsible process, as shown in `top`:

```
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 191 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5,6 us, 11,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 83,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :    437,5 total,     14,4 free,    363,9 used,     59,2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1952,0 total,   1836,7 free,    115,2 used.     62,1 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    651 root      20   0   91292   2684   2276 S   6,2   0,6   0:04.37 vmtoolsd
      1 root      20   0  165324   2636   2200 S   0,0   0,6   0:02.18 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.35 ksoftirqd/0
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.74 rcu_sched
     13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 migration/0
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
     18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 netns
     19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kauditd
     20 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
```

and `free -m`:

```
Mem:             437         363           5           0          68          52
Swap:           1951         113        1838
```

I checked if it's being used by a tmpfs with `mount | grep tmpfs`

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=204664k,nr_inodes=51166,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=44804k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=44800k,nr_inodes=11200,mode=700)
```

but each of them don't use much memory in `df -h`

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   200M     0  200M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   44M  976K   43M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01  7,4G  4,8G  2,3G  69% /
tmpfs                  219M     0  219M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/loop1              64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1828
/dev/loop3             117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14784
/dev/loop2              64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1852
/dev/loop4              45M   45M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2913
/dev/loop0             117M  117M     0 100% /snap/core/14946
/dev/loop5              44M   44M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2836
/dev/sda1              462M   85M  349M  20% /boot
tmpfs                   44M  4,0K   44M   1% /run/user/0
```

Not sure if relevant but this is the output of `systemd-cgtop -m`

```
Control Group                                                         Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s
/                                                                       217      -   425.3M        -        -
system.slice                                                             51    0.1    75.8M        -        -
system.slice/nagios-nrpe-server-args.service                              1      -    11.7M        -        -
user.slice                                                                5    1.5     9.9M        -        -
system.slice/snapd.service                                                9    0.0     9.7M        -        -
user.slice/user-0.slice                                                   5    1.5     9.6M        -        -
user.slice/user-0.slice/session-1.scope                                   3    1.5     7.8M        -        -
system.slice/apache2.service                                              7    0.0     6.2M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-journald.service                                     1      -     5.7M        -        -
system.slice/cron.service                                                 1      -     3.9M        -        -
init.scope                                                                1      -     3.6M        -        -
system.slice/mariadb.service                                              8    0.0     2.3M        -        -
system.slice/open-vm-tools.service                                        2    0.1     2.1M        -        -
system.slice/ssh.service                                                  1      -     1.7M        -        -
system.slice/ifup@ens192.service                                          8      -     1.3M        -        -
system.slice/rsyslog.service                                              4      -     1.1M        -        -
user.slice/user-0.slice/user@0.service                                    2      -     1.1M        -        -
system.slice/systemd-udevd.service                                        1      -   888.0K        -        -
system.slice/dbus.service                                                 1      -   736.0K        -        -
system.slice/system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice                                 -      -   708.0K        -        -
system.slice/vsftpd.service                                               1      -   656.0K        -        -
system.slice/systemd-logind.service                                       1      -   560.0K        -        -
system.slice/system-getty.slice                                           1      -   432.0K        -        -
```

I read that ballooning could be the issue but `vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon` returns

```
0 MB
```

System info with `hostnamectl`

```
Static hostname: localhost
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 24fcbea78a5643359430d9f0b6721da1
           Boot ID: 96efe542e3ae466898f9e5508368c4ff
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-21-amd64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I tried restarting the server and stopping Apache with no results, not sure what I could try now.